# Get the value from the string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Here is example of my string: "https://dev.testapi.com/api/v1/properties?id:xyz&surname:kronenberg&active=true". Question is: i want to save the last value of my string, in this case its "active:".

Another examples of the string:

```js
var url =  "https://dev.testapi.com/api/v1/properties?id=xyz&surname:kronenberg&property_type:true";
var url =  "https://dev.testapi.com/api/v1/properties?id=xyz&surname:kronenberg&active:true";
var url =  "https://dev.testapi.com/api/v1/properties?id=xyz&surname:kronenberg&user_id:true";
```

= "https://dev.testapi.com/api/v1/properties?id=xyz&surname:kronenberg&property_type:true"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Comment: i want just get the last value from the string just parse it with regex and thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var url1 = '"https://dev.testapi.com/api/v1/properties?id=xyz&surname:kronenberg&property_type:true"',
    url2 = '"https://dev.testapi.com/api/v1/properties?id=xyz&surname:kronenberg&active:true"',
    url3 = '"https://dev.testapi.com/api/v1/properties?id=xyz&surname:kronenberg&user_id:true"',
    url4 = '"dev.testapi.com/api/v1/properties?id=xyz"';

    console.log(url1.match(/(?!.+[&?])(\w+)/g)[0]);
    console.log(url2.match(/(?!.+[&?])(\w+)/g)[0]);
    console.log(url3.match(/(?!.+[&?])(\w+)/g)[0]);
    console.log(url4.match(/(?!.+[&?])(\w+)/g)[0]);
```

Comment: but in this case its not working var url1 = '"https://dev.testapi.com/api/v1/properties?id=xyz"' if it will be only one value

Comment: But if i got only one query its not working...
 url4 = '"dev.testapi.com/api/v1/properties?id=xyz"',

Comment: Thx, have a nice day!

Comment: No problem dude! ) You save my day !)

Answer (score 0):

See my demo in action here [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QCAael/1).

`(\w+)(?:(?:=|:)\w+)?$` is the required regex in Javascript.

`(\w+)` Sets a [capturing group](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups).

`?:` When inside a capturing group, denote a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon).

`$` denotes end of the statement.